# Facebook friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
<?php

require_once 'facebook/facebook.php';

$appapikey = 'xx';
$appsecret = 'yy';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();

echo "<p>Hello, <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" />!</p>";

echo "<p>Friends:";
$friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_get();
$friends = array_slice($friends, 0, 15);
foreach ($friends as $friend) {
echo "<br><fb:profile-pic uid='$friend'><fb:name uid=\"$friend\" useyou=\"false\" /></fb:profile-pic>";
}
echo "</p>";

?>
```

How can I run it? I do not know the new codes. Waiting for your help please :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [PHP SDK for the Facebook API](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) for this.

```
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));
```

To get the list of friends:

```
$friendsLists = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

foreach ($friendsLists as $friends) {
  foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    $id = $friend['id'];
    $name = $friend['name'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello
Thank you for your help.
I want to show my friends pictures and names to 10.
How do I do?
Which is required to get permission?

Answer (score 2):

I extended the answer above by Gaurav to include a limiter and shuffler.

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($friendsLists as $friends) {
    shuffle($friends);
    foreach ($friends as $friend) {
        $id = $friend['id'];
        $name = $friend['name'];
        echo $name;
        echo "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" . $id ."/picture'><br>";
        if (++$i == 5) break;
    }
}
```